# can bloodcursed arrows still be used after Harkon is dead?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

So I've finished the main quest line for Dawngaurd, but now I'm trying to use the bloodcursed arrows to block the sun, can this be done since I decided to kill Harkon?

Comment: As I am not 100% sure I will post it as a comment, but I am pretty sure they should still work. You do need to use the right bow though.

Answer (score 2):

Harkon, like you apparently, is just someone who wants to use the power of the bow.  He does not give it power.  The bow's abilities when shooting the sun with *both* types of special arrow work fine after Harkon is dead.  Though the "Clear Skies" shout is often required to *find* the sun in Skyrim.

The only thing I'm not sure of is if the bow needs to have available "soul gem power" to activate those abilities.  Personally, I just keep it charged.  It's remarkably low capacity makes it a good use for your smaller soul gems.